# Is it possible to add UISwitch programmatically in iPhone Setting Bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsbundle

In my iOS app, I have 9 `UISwitch` added in the `Root.plist`. I can  control it from both Phone Setting and Application easily and can save `NSUserDefaults` successfully for fixed value.

Now I need to add some more `UISwitch` programmatically for user defined value in run time. Should i create custom Setting bundle to do it?

If yes, then how ?
Is it possible from code?
Any Solution?

Comment: hi tulon, are you  from dhaka ? can i get your mail please ? @Tulon

Comment: Hello, Yes I'm. I'm afraid not. Please mention your email address here.

Comment: jamshed.bas@gmail.com

Comment: Hello Jamshed, Just wondering what will you do with my mail address. Is it mail or Email address??

Comment: ha ha.. i am wondering also. I asked your mail(Actually Email), you are from BD and working in iOS platform. Just for keeping contact. Thanks Bro. :)

Comment: Here it is:
Email : reashedzamiltulon@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings bundle is simply an xml file that is bundled with the app. You don't have access to this at runtime; you should include dynamic settings within your app.

Comment: do you have any perfect link to do a dynamic settings ?

Comment: Look on github for an existing solution https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=settings+iphone&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=✓

Comment: ^^ Don't think me rude for the comment: I am linking to the search page so it will update dynamically for people with the same question :)